# Can you prove a statement with a row of if and only ifs?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, fake-proofs

For example, I have the following exercise:
$\text{“Prove that if }N\text{ is normal and }AN=0\text{, then }AN^\star = 0”.$

I know that an $\textbf{Incorrect}$ way to prove this would be 
$AN^\star = 0 \implies$ (Multiplying by $N$)
$AN^\star N = 0 \implies$  ($N$ is normal)
$ANN^\star = 0 \implies$ (Because $AN = 0$) 
$0 = 0\;$

Q.E.D
(The mistake here is that we assumed what we needed to prove)

But is the following proof correct?

First we'll prove a lemma:
“If $AA^\star = 0$, Then $A = 0$.”

Let $V$ be a vector space.

$AA^\star = 0 \implies \forall x\in V : \langle AA^\star x, x \rangle = 0 \implies \langle A^\star x, A^\star x \rangle = 0 \implies ||A^\star x||^2 = 0 \implies A^\star x = 0 \implies A^\star = 0 \implies A = 0$

$AN^\star = 0 \iff$
$AN^\star (AN^\star)^\star = 0 \iff$(Conjugate properties)
$AN^\star NA^\star = 0 \iff (N$  is normal)
$ANN^\star A^\star = 0 \iff$ (Because $AN = 0)$ 
$0 = 0$
Which is true, and we used if-and-only-ifs and therefore $AN^\star = 0$.

Is the second proof correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The very first $\;\iff\;$ is unjustified...so far. The direction $\;\implies\;$ is trivially true always, yet the directon $\;\Longleftarrow\;$ isn't...

Comment: What justifies the first equivalence?

Comment: Fixed. extracharacterssssssss

Comment: Yes, the second argument is correct.

Comment: Ok great! Thanks everyone!

Comment: I think it is correct. You can as well use the following: $Nx=0$ iff $N^*x=0.$ Indeed $\|Nx\|^2=\langle Nx,Nx\rangle =\langle N^*Nx,x\rangle =\langle NN^*x,x\rangle =\langle N^*x,N^*x\rangle=\|N^*x\|^2.$ Then $AN=0$ iff $N^*A^*=0$ iff $NA^*=0$ iff  $AN^*=0.$